# What is wrong with my creation of objects when I try to use a variable for a key?

Tags: javascript

I have these lines of code to transform an array

```
const regex = new RegExp(req.params.keyword, 'i');
const fields = ['fname', 'lname'];
const arrayOfRegex = [];
// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
for (const f of fields) {
  arrayOfRegex.push({ f: regex });
}
console.log(arrayOfRegex);
```

My expected output is

```
[{ fname: /pyt/i }, { lname: /pyt/i }]
```

But I got this what went wrong?

```
[ { f: /pyt/i }, { f: /pyt/i } ]
```

Comment: You need dynamic key, use square brackets `{ [f]: regex }`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either `forEach` nor `for` (nor `for...of)`. The problem you describe is not at all related to any loop. In the future *be clear* what the problem is, do not attribute it to something unrelated. The point of asking a question is to provide something useful for other people to search for. Looking up problems with loops and finding information about building objects is not useful to them.